# Change specific values with lambda in dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, lambda

I'm trying to change specific values in dictionary. I have this Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<String, Dictionary<IProduct, bool>> productList;
```

I want to select specific Keys and then change Values to true using lambda. I have this type of code:

```
var pairs = productList["A"].Where(p => !p.Value).Take(2);
```

I have tryed to use *foreach*:

```
foreach(var pair in pairs)
{
    productList["A"][pair.Key] = true;
}
```

but I got this error:
**Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.**

Thanks!

Comment: Just change it to `foreach(var pair in pairs.ToArray())`

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks! works for me :)